# PDF creation function crashes after deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, iis, itext

I have method, which creates a pdf file from the view, based on information retrieved from the model. It works without any problem on my pc in debug mode, however after deployment on IIS server (different machine) it started crashing.
I have granted full access to all user on a map with assembly but it didn't help.
Error message is useless it only says that "something went wrong"

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

My Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmployeesForExamination(List<EmployeeListForHealthExamination> model)
    {
        List<EmployeeListForHealthExamination> listForPrint = new List<EmployeeListForHealthExamination>();
        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            if (item.printDoc)
            {
                return CreatePDF(item);
            }
        }
        return View(model);   
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ReportForHE(EmployeeListForHealthExamination model)
    {
        using (var db = new HRMEntities())
        {
            model.harmingFactorList = db.EmployeeHarmingFactors.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == model.EmployeeId).ToList();
            return PartialView("Partial/_ReportHE", model);
        }
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult CreatePDF(EmployeeListForHealthExamination model)
    {
        return new ActionAsPdf("ReportForHE", model)
        {
            FileName = model.FirstName + model.LastName + "HealthExamination.pdf"
        };
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you get access to view the stack trace/error log?  That'll provide some major clues to what is going wrong.

Comment: @nockieboy Is it it?

Comment: if you can, execute wkhtmltopdf from command line on he server to check it works on that machine. Where is it hosted? Your server? Azure? Vhost?

Comment: Also, you can get around those problems entirely if you choose to use a SaaS API. I've set up https://rotativahq.com for this.

Comment: @GiorgioBozio Server can not recognize this command.
I have my own server for private purposes: IIS server

Comment: @Vadim.K I mean try from command line. If it doesn't work from there, then there something missing from the server, for example GDI libs.

Comment: @GiorgioBozio Do you mean like this?(Post edited)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123536/discussion-between-vadim-k-and-giorgio-bozio).

Comment: You are using wkhtml yet you tag this question as an iText question. Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue could be because of lack of visual c++ of an old version of your visual c++ on server, try to upgrade it.